# InnoTools Downloader not working with Inno 5.5

Tags: inno-setup, inno-tools-downloader

On the recommendation of several posts here on SO, I've been working with the InnoTools Downloader to try to install a 3rd party dependency for our app during the Install script in Inno setup.

Unfortunately the InnoTools Downloader hasn't been updated in a few years, and is starting to look like it's incompatible with the current Inno Tools setup (5.5.2 (u) on my machine at present). The PChar parameters in ITD have been replaced by PAnsiChar parameters, and when I try to run the various ITD_xxx procedures it gives me varying degrees of fail:

- `ITD_DownloadFiles` gives a type mismatch error and won't compile in Inno Setup
- `ITD_DownloadFile` compiles, but the file that shows up is 6KB in length and not runnable.

Has anyone gotten ITP to run with newer Inno (post-5.3.0) unicode versions? Or should I look around for another solution?

EDIT
Just to clarify things a bit, I have tried going into the it_download.iss file and replacing all instances of PChar with PAnsiChar. This got me past the compile errors when I first tried to integrate ITD with my setup script.

Here is a sample section of the Inno script:

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  ITD_Init; // initialize the InnoTools Downloader
  // install 3rd party tool (ex. Git) from the internet.
  if ITD_DownloadFile('http://git-scm.com/download/win',expandconstant('{tmp}\GitInstaller.exe'))=ITDERR_SUCCESS then begin
     MsgBox(expandconstant('{tmp}\GitInstaller.exe'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
     Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\GitInstaller.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, tmpResult);
  end
end;
```

When this is run, it will bring up a dialog stating where it "downloaded" and stored the file -- on my machine it's in a subdirectory of c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp. This file is 6KB, as opposed to the file downloaded from http://git-scm.com/download/win, which is currently 15,221KB.

The `ITP_DownloadAfter` method gives a similar result.

Comment: "When I try to run" without showing us what you're doing isn't helpful, and neither is "gives a type mismatch error and won't compile" without the specific error message and line that is generating the error. Pre-Delphi 2009 `PChar` is the equivalent of D2009 and later `PAnsiChar`, but without specifics of the problem you're having it's hard to recommend a solution.

Comment: Except replacement of `PChar` to `PAnsiChar` you must replace `string` with `AnsiString`.

Comment: @KenWhite - Thanks - I just added a [code] section to describe what I've tried so far.

Comment: @TLama - Thanks. I had done the PChar->PAnsiChar replace in the it_download.iss file; I just replaced the strings with AnsiStrings. Doesn't look like it helped any. :-( I found another Inno plugin that I might look into as an alternative if I can't get this running (here: http://mitrich.net23.net/?/inno-download-plugin.html).

Comment: It works for me. I've just replaced `PChar` with `PAnsiChar` and `string` with `AnsiString` and tried the code you posted. The problem is now that you're downloading a web site instead of a GIT installer binary. Check the content of the downloaded file. It's a HTML document.

Comment: For the record, I faced this same issue, and chose to go about writing my own DLL for this, using a common form which is also identical to another DLL for unzipping ZIP files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Except replacing all `PChar` type occurrences with `PAnsiChar` you will need to replace all occurrences of `string` type with `AnsiString` in the `it_download.iss` file. The next problem is the URL you're trying to get. The size of a file differs from expectation, because you are downloading a HTML document instead of the binary file on which that site redirects. So, if you have your ITD ready for Unicode, change the URL in your script to a [`direct binary URL`](http://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/Git-1.8.4-preview20130916.exe). Note, that I didn't used HTTPS because ITD doesn't currently support SSL. A code proof may look like this:

```pascal
[Code]
const
  GitSetupURL = 'http://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/Git-1.8.4-preview20130916.exe';

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  Name: string;
  Size: Integer;
begin
  Name := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\GitInstaller.exe');

  ITD_Init;  
  if ITD_DownloadFile(GitSetupURL, Name) = ITDERR_SUCCESS then
  begin
    if FileSize(Name, Size) then
      MsgBox(Name + #13#10 + 'Size: ' + IntToStr(Size) + ' B',
        mbInformation, MB_OK)
    else
      MsgBox('FileSize function failed!', mbError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ack (bangs head against desk). This was the issue -- lovely redirects! Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, I would expect from IDT redirect handling, although it seems it doesn't have any support for it. Strange...

Comment: Converting `string` to `AnsiString` was throwing "incompatible type" errors. It worked without replacing them.