# Download based on the task selected with Inno Download Plugin?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-download-plugin

I have been having a couple of problems trying to achieve what I want and I will discuss each issue separately. It concerns a help documentation setup file which I has asked about before. But now I am using IDP I need to change my logic and have it wrong.

Firstly, I have this task:

```
Name: "downloadhelp"; Description: "{cm:DownloadHelpTask}"; \
    GroupDescription: "{cm:DownloadHelpGroup}"; Flags: unchecked
```

Then I added this:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
    if CurPageID = wpReady then
    begin
        if (WizardIsTaskSelected('downloadhelp')) then
            AddFileForDownload('{#HelpDocSetupURL}', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe'));
    end;

    WizardForm.CancelButton.Top := WizardForm.NextButton.Top;
end;
```

And this is in `[Run]` section:

```
Filename: "{app}\HelpDocSetup.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/SP- /VERYSILENT /InstallPath=""{app}"""; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: waituntilterminated runhidden; \
    Description: "{cm:InstallingHelpDescription}"; \
    StatusMsg: "{cm:InstallingHelpStatusMessage}"; \
    Tasks: downloadhelp
```

But when I am on my "ready" page the file is not listed for download.

When exactly is is Ok to add a file to download based on the task being selected?

I realize now that `wpReady` means we have already filled the memo content. Previously I was using this line:

```
;Source: "{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe"; \
;    DestDir: "{app}"; \
;    Flags: external deleteafterinstall; \
;    Tasks: downloadhelp; \
;    Check: DwinsHs_Check( ExpandConstant('{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe'), '{#HelpDocSetupURL}', \
;            'My_Setup', 'Get', {#HelpDocSetupFileSize}, 0 )
```

The task is listed correctly:

[image]

But I need to add it if the task is selected.
It is now obsolete. What do I do?

I see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56439471/downloading-file-with-inno-setup-only-when-user-chooses-to) but it relates to components and not tasks.

The second answer [here](https://itqna.net/questions/7935/download-during-installation-inno-setup) sounds possible solution.

Based on the linked answer I added:

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: integer): boolean;
begin
    Result := True;

    if(CurPageID = wpSelectTasks) then
    begin
        if WizardIsTaskSelected('downloadhelp') then
            AddFileForDownload('{#HelpDocSetupURL}', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe'));
    end;
end;
```

But this is flawed. If the user uses next / back it keeps adding the file multiple times to the list of files to download and my memo ready page lists all of them.

I tried changing it to use components and the "Download Help" listed there. Then I was able to simply use `idpAddFileComp` in `InitializeWizard` but then I end up with the former problem of listing the file as needing to be downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no really elegant way to solve this with IDP.

One way is to call `idpClearFiles` in `BackButtonClick(wpReady)`.

For this to work, you will of course need to be adding all files in `NextButtonClick(wpSelectTasks)` – Even those that are added unconditionally.

Comment: I did it your way in the end (and remembered to reset that `FilesToDownload` variable. Looks OK.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was the best way, but at least it works.

## Step 1

I added a new `[Components]` section like this:

```
[Components]
Name: downloadhelpcomponent; Description: "{cm:DownloadHelpTask}"
```

## Step 2

I commented out the previous `[Tasks]` entry:

```
[Tasks]
;Name: "downloadhelp"; Description: "{cm:DownloadHelpTask}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:DownloadHelpGroup}"; Flags: unchecked
```

## Step 3

I added the following to `initializeWizard`:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    idpAddFileSizeComp('{#HelpDocSetupURL}', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe'), {#HelpDocSetupFileSize}, 'downloadhelpcomponent');

    idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);

    { Make download wizard page resizeable }
    IDPForm.TotalProgressBar.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
    IDPForm.FileProgressBar.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight];
    IDPForm.TotalDownloaded.Anchors := [akTop, akRight];
    IDPForm.FileDownloaded.Anchors := [akTop, akRight];
    IDPForm.DetailsButton.Anchors := [akTop, akRight];
end;
```

When I run this installer the page looks like this:

[image: Components]

The main problem here is that it has decided this component is 56MB and that is wrong! The file is actually 7.28MB. Although I suppose the 56MB is the whole setup. Also, the various "Types" don't really make sense, but if I remove them I lose the check box choices.

## Step 4

I adjusted the `UpdateReadyMeno` output like this:

```pascal
function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, 
                         NewLine, 
                         MemoUserInfoInfo, 
                         MemoDirInfo, 
                         MemoTypeInfo, 
                         MemoComponentsInfo, 
                         MemoGroupInfo, 
                         MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
begin
    Result := '';
    if MemoUserInfoInfo <> '' then
        Result := Result + MemoUserInfoInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
    if MemoDirInfo <> '' then
        Result := Result + MemoDirInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
    if MemoComponentsInfo <> '' then
        Result := Result + MemoComponentsInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
    if MemoGroupInfo <> '' then
        Result := Result + MemoGroupInfo + NewLine + NewLine;
    if (MemoTasksInfo <> '') then
        Result := Result + MemoTasksInfo + NewLine + NewLine;

    { Only display the Auto Backup Settings info if it is a new install }
    if (not bIsUpgrading) then
        Result := Result + AutoBackupPage_MemoInfo(Space, NewLine);

    if ((FilesToDownload <> '') or WizardIsComponentSelected('downloadhelpcomponent')) then
    begin
        Result := Result + ExpandConstant('{cm:ReadyMemo_Download}') + NewLine;

        if(FilesToDownload <> '') then
            Result := Result + FilesToDownload;

        if(IsComponentSelected('downloadhelpcomponent')) then
            Result := Result + Space + 'HelpDocSetup.exe' + NewLine;
    end;
end;
```

So, if the component is selected my Ready page looks like this:

[image: Ready memo]

## Step 5

Finally, I adjusted the `[Run]` entry:

```
Filename: "{tmp}\HelpDocSetup.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/SP- /VERYSILENT /InstallPath=""{app}"""; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: waituntilterminated runhidden; \
    Description: "{cm:InstallingHelpDescription}"; \
    StatusMsg: "{cm:InstallingHelpStatusMessage}"; \
    Components: downloadhelpcomponent
```

This approach (which is documented in the IDP help files) seems to be the best way.